# How to link implementation to an interface from another library?

Tags: c++, interface, static-libraries

My objective is I have several library A, B, C and etc.. All of the libraries will link to a Core Library. The question is in Core Library, there is a class "Calculation_Util" will require a implementation from the Library A, B, C, and etc.

What is the topic or module that can resolve my problem?

[image: The relationship between my question.]

Elaborate 1

1. I want to build a library which contain a function is depends on a function from outside the library.

Comment: I didn't understand question clearly but if this helps, create seperate source files and include only one of the library A or B or C and implement the interface.

Comment: @moonshines no, what i want is at Library A i could tell Core Library to use Beta_implementation from Library A, and when at Library B will use Beta_implementation from Library B. All of these Library will at the same project.

Comment: Can you elaborate more with an example. Which interface is in which class and which class is trying to access them?

Comment: @moonshines to be simple, I want to build a library which contain a function is depends on a function from outside the library.

Comment: Depending on the lifetimes of this interface, couldn't you use either dependency injection techniques to pass in the implementation as needed or even a service-locator pattern if the lifetime is meant to be static?

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible in C++. All linked libraries must follow [object-oriented design](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_design). This means one library is base and the other links to it.

So if A, B, C have their own implementations, you can link only one of them to Core. It's different from functional programming like Python where you can just link all of them together.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I would change my design instead.